# Setting up a javascript url

Tags: javascript

I simply want to set up an ajaxurl in javascript to pass to my controller.

When trying to setup the url, it evaluates to **0** during the below attempts:
Note that attrs.attachmentType & attrs.attachmentId have values associated with them.

```
var hoser = attrs.attachmentType & attrs.attachmentId;

                                ajaxUrl = root + 'FileUpload/upload?' & 'Type=' & attrs.attachmentType & 'ID=' & attrs.attachmentId;
```

If I just include the following, a proper value is seen inside the hoser variable.

```
var hoser = attrs.attachmentType;
```

**What am I doing wrong where the url will not come out correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `&` symbols, not adding them to the string. By using these symbols, javascript is interpreting the right hand side of your statement to be a comparison and outputting the answer it thinks you want - in this case, a boolean representation of false: `0`

Change your `&` symbols to strings. Like so:

```
 ajaxUrl = root + 'FileUpload/upload?' + '&' + 'Type=' + '&' + attrs.attachmentType + '&' + 'ID=' + '&' + attrs.attachmentId;
```